# My key is stuck in a lock after using another key from the other side

Tags: lock

Last night I was locked out of my house so I tried to use the spare set of keys to open the door.

When opening the door I realized that another key was in the other side of the door. I put pressure on the spare set of keys in order to push the other keys out (this may have been a mistake), this worked and I was able to open the door. However I can now only remove the keys from the lock if the door is locked. Has anyone got any suggestions or will I have to buy a new lock?

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this.

Comment: What type of lock? Might be helpful to edit that information (or a photo) into your question.

Comment: you don't need a new lock, unless you pushed way harder than described. it's a feature (key retention), of some quality locks, not a bug. You need both keys again, and then you can change the key retention option, typically by reversing your actions or turning the set key the other rotational direction. If you can't get it reset, it should be a quick job for a locksmith and again likely won't require swapping hardware. Then again, maybe something simply busted and i'm way off, hard to tell from here...

Comment: Try partially removing the lock assembly, that should free it up enough to the keys out.